# Why does my transmitted variable always remain empty?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

**Hi,** recently I tried to send a variable from ViewController 1 :

```
guard let viewController2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as? ViewController2 else
                {
                    fatalError("Error when trying to get the reference to the Step 2")
                }
        viewController2.testName = TextFieldOutlet.text!
```

To ViewController2 :

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTest: UILabel!
    
    public var testName = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelTest.text = testName
    }
    
}
```

All the code seems to be correct but my label and my variable in the ViewController2 remain empty.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Code looks fine, you should debug it.
print(TextFieldOutlet.text) before setting it to viewController2.testName.
or use breakpoints to find out the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I try to print my TextField and I get: "Optional("Test")" so it works. Even if I replace "viewController2.testName = TextFieldOutlet.text" with "viewController2.testName = "John"" it still doesn't work. Do you have an idea of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can just instead of calling it, you need to trigger it by action that's why I've added a button like in the image and make connection between it and viewController2 and worked with its segue and it worked fine

The image:
[image]

Code added in viewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
     let viewController2 = segue.destination as! ViewController2
     viewController2.testName = TextFieldOutlet.text!
    
    
}
```